# Why do languages have operator precedence?

Tags: operator-precedence

Why not simply evaluate Left to Right? Can someone explain how precedence makes code more readable? To me it seems to require more thought and more possibility for error. Einstein said, "Everything should be made as simple as possible, but no simpler." I guess he wasn't a programmer.

Comment: That applies even for mathematics , operator precedence !

Comment: Operator precedence is learned in 7th grade in my country. A computer programmer must have way above that level of schooling IMO.

Comment: In some sense, but in another that is not true. Children can write programs without knowing math. Mozart wrote a piece of music which is still performed, when he was 3. I don't like the implication that programming requires a lot of schooling, it is not true.

Comment: I learned in grade 3 myself. I've used dozens of languages and I only ever encountered one without operator precedence.

Comment: All cars are painted, but the DeLorean got by without it. You have not explained WHY precedence is there.

Comment: I haven't attempted to. I am commenting. Comments aren't answers.

Comment: I am looking for answers. Is that a separate section : ) ?

Answer (score 5):

because in Mathematics, before the invention of any computer language, there was operator precedence, e.g.

```
2 + 5 * 3 = 17 (and not 21)
```

A language not having a higher precedence for the `*` operator than for the `+` operator would generate confusion.

Another example from C++:

```
std::cout << 7 * 8 << std::endl;
```

If the `*` operator did not have precedence over the `<<` operator, this would not compile:

- `std::cout << 7` would be evaluated first, yielding `std::cout` as a result (with the side effect that `7` would be printed)
- then one would want to evaluate `std::cout * 8` which -- unless somebody defines a really weird operator `*` for multiplying an `outputstream` by an integer  -- is not defined.

Operator precedence allows not having to put unnecessary parentheses 'within common sense' (although I agree that in some cases people introduce bugs because they are not aware of the actual precedences)

---

Now you might ask: why does Mathematics have operator precedence ? [This wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_of_operations) mentions some historical facts and links to [a discussion forum](https://web.archive.org/web/20180111045655/http://mathforum.org/library/drmath/view/52582.html). For me, an imporant argument is the one that when writing polynomials, e.g.

```
ax^2 + bx + c
```

without operator precedence, one would have to write them as:

```
(a(x^2)) + (bx) + c
```

Comment: So it has to do with the fact that there are two "streams of evaluation" that come together at some point? In your example, The first part in parens and the second part in parens are independent and both "happen" before the first plus is evaluated. I guess I would break it up into separate statements and use temporary variables if it was that complex. Is that so hard?

Comment: You mentioned simplicity, I claim `ax^2 + bx + c` is simpler to write (at the price of agreeing to some rules of precedence). You say 'breaking up into separate statements' is simpler to understand (at the price of having to read and write more). Both ways are simpler in some sense...

Comment: Which of these ways of looking at the equation would be more natural for _completing the square_? The one without parentheses. Important mathematical structure is lost in recourse to temporary variables. Although it is true that optimal _evaluation_ of a polynomial uses Horner's rule and that's a parenthesis jungle…

Answer (score 2):

The purpose of precedence is not to make it more readable, its to (a) standardize and (b) keep with standards set in mathematics, such as PEMDAS.

Comment: Keep with a standard in an entirely different realm that evolved hundreds of years before programming. WHY?

Comment: @AndrewLazarus He has a legitimate question, dont hound him for that. As for why, think about something in the world that is non-standardized but could be, like a charger. It would help alot if there was one charger that fits everything. This is basically the same thing - it would be very confusion is 2 + 3 * 4 meant one thing  in math and a different thing in programming.

Comment: @Dgrin91, I don't mind the question _per se_, but his follow-up comments look more argumentative than anything else.

Comment: I do wonder why we can't follow Occam's Rule, but I guess we would sell fewer chargers that way. I just don't like it when we set out to build a system, and the reason for something is "because we did it that way before." Not good enough.

Comment: @user2494563 Well there is good reasoning behind PEMDAS, which inherently follows through to programming.

Comment: But peoples' answers say "to avoid confusion simplify expressions, break them up and use parens". If you are going most of the way, why not go all the way? What does PEDMAS buy us in a programming scenario except in trivially simple cases? Programming code does not look like an expression on a blackboard. They are different realms.

Comment: @user2494563 Often times it can look very similar, just longer variable names. And the reason we dont take the parentheses all the way is because it gets clunky and annoying (and even confusing) if you do it too much. So instead we expect that our fellow programmers will have a modicum of intellect so that we dont have to explicitly say that 2+3*4 is equivalent to 2+(3*4)

Answer (score 2):

[APL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/APL_%28programming_language%29) does not have operator precedence (except parentheses); code reads right to left (like Hebrew or Arabic). That said, APL is a niche language and this is one reason why. Most other languages, as other answers already point out, mimic the long-established precedence rules of arithmetic, which in turn appear to me to arise from how typical use cases (i.e., real-world problems) can be modeled with a minimum number of parentheses.

Comment: OK, but mathematics arose before Shift, dereferencing, boolean operators, etc. Languages can have a dozen or more precedence levels, which no sane person would build in to a system that real people were meant to use. It's like saying: 100 lemmings went off the cliff because 10 did. More is not always better. At some point we should call a halt and say, nope, the forest is getting too think in that direction. Or, as BASIC used to bark: "Redo from Start", or just "?"

Comment: Again, I suggest that the precedence table was chosen in an attempt to minimize the need for manual grouping, i.e., parentheses, in the most frequent use cases. If you want an example where this has broken, the use of `<<` as overloaded insertion operator on C++ streams often requires parentheses because its precedence is more appropriate to bit-shift. If you find the C/Java precedence table too complex, no one is stopping you from inserting redundant parentheses: I think this is _good_ practice in tricky cases or to emphasize an expression's structure.

Answer (score 1):

The digital world simply follows the old-school "real" world where the `BEDMAS` rules: Brackets, Exponents, Division, Multiplication, Addition, Subtraction.

Better to follow the real world, than try to refedefine reality and end up with programmers doing

```
1 + 2 * 3
```

as

```
(1 + 2) * 3 = 9
```

v.s. a realworlder doing

```
1 + (2 * 3) = 7
```

and sending your multimillion dollar probe into an invalid atmospheric descent profile because someone "carried the 1" wrong.

Comment: ...didn't this almost happened http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mars_Climate_Orbiter

Comment: yep. miles v.s. kilometers or something. or was it pounds v.s. kilograms? Either way, incredibly STUPID mistake.

Comment: pound-seconds vs newton-seconds

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to do away with precedence rules - or more correctly, have just one such rule - as [APL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/APL_%28programming_language%29) demonstrates.

> "It has just one simple, consistent, and recursive precedence rule: the right argument of a function is the result of the entire expression to the right of that function."

For example, in "J" (an APL variant):

```
  1+2*3   => 7      Computed as  1+(2*3)
  2*3+1   => 8      Computed as  2*(3+1)
```

APL (and J) has so many operators, it would be difficult to remember the precedence and associativity rules of each and every one of them.

Comment: "1 2 3 many"  I think it gets thick fast. 12 levels as in C is too many to keep straight. Bust. You waste more time referring to a chart than writing that one statement differently.

Answer (score 1):

The reason why there is an operator precedence is because you should see a sum like `2*4` as a WHOLE number.

So you could think of it in a way that `2*4` doesn't exist. It's simply `8`.

So what you're basically doing is "simplifying" the sum, like: `2+10*2` This basically says: `2+20`.

As in the following sum: `2143+8^2+6^9`. You don't want to write out `2143+262144+10077696`. (And imagine how this could look like if you have a much larger formula)

It's basically to simplify the look of the sum. And both addition and subtraction are the most basic form of operations. So that's why there is a precedence, it is to increase the readbility of the sum.

And like i said, since the `+` and `-` operators are the most basic operators there are, then it makes sense to first solve the more "complicated" operators.

Comment: OK. But there are a lot of operators in programming, and eventually visual cues and brain-power give out. So why create a stone that becomes too heavy to lift?

Comment: This handwaving doesn't explain anything.

Comment: @EJP Ok, so if this isn't the reason according to you, then **WHY** do they exist according to you? The "real" answer clearly originates from mathematics. All the other given answers don't give any clear reason WHY they are there in mathematics, why they were "invented". So what's your answer then?

Comment: I am only concerned about programming languages, so all the talk about expressions in math is irrelevant. A blackboard is not a text editor. An equation is not a programming statement. I don't want an answer to W00's question, and I am not sure what EJP means about handwaving not explaining. Is he agreeing with me? or what? We could dispense with precedence entirely in programming, or substantially, and I don't see any relevance to math or anything else. I am merely trying to save people time and trouble in writing programs. Aside from (too) complex math formulas, how does it improve things?

Comment: @user2494563 I assumed your question was about mathematical operators only. My bad. But if it were the case (still like to point out), it's simply there (in programming languages) becasue it's there in math. So in other words, for consistency. Would be weird to introduce a totally new way of writing formulas in code, right? Anyway, that's enough about this handwaving math explanation for me.

Comment: This handwaving explanation actually does explain why it exists, in maths at least. It obviously indrectly explains why it is there in programming languages as well (math precedence that is). And even if he's wrong, then don't come in with an arrogant attitude, saying that it's wrong without telling WHY it is wrong. That's not helping anyone and you're not really convincing either without backing your argument with proper facts.

Comment: It's handwaving because it doesn't explain *why* the product of 2 and 4 should be considered a 'single number', the argument at this point being in fact completely circular; and it's irrelevant because the question isn't about why operator precedence exists, it is about why it exists in programming languages. See the title.

Answer (score 0):

For example, with operator precedence the following evaluates to **14**:

```
2 + 3 * 4
```

without it would evaluate to **20** which is unexpected, imho.

Comment: To me, nothing is "expected" because we get to define it. What is SIMPLER to understand? That should be what is expected. A toy expression with 2 operators is not the way to model a system. All the answers I have been able to find amount to: A) break it up into smaller statements (lines of code) B) use parens when there could be confusion. So why not simply say: L to R except where parens change that. Period - Question mark? What does precedence DO for us - Interrogatory? What does it DO???

Comment: L to R would be unexpected since those are math expressions and that's the standard for math expressions. If you find it weird, then learn Math before learning how to program a computer.

Comment: I think that math and programming have nothing to do with each other. 99% of the time programming is about doing things sequentially and making decisions, which is not part of math. This is why cooking - involving recipes - is not math, and recipes are the #1 example of what an algorithm is. I don't know any chefs with math degrees, and very little programming has math more complex than what 5th grader could do, yet we seem to think they are the same thing. I don't see it. If they are so different, treat them differently.

Comment: Computers were invented to compute calculations. That's math to me! They're now used for so much more because they became to useful. Still, most of the deep core algorithms have their roots in math. Cryptography, search, even games with physics and 3D graphics

Comment: OK, so computers started from a need to solve math problems. Fine. This reminds me of when I learnt that the "socket" was originally conceived as a form of IPC on a *single* machine (that is, before networks existed.) It took me days to get over that, as if cars had been invented merely to drive down to the mailbox. A Network, who would have thunk it? So that is what the here answers are saying...

Answer (score 0):

Take an example , if there were no operator precedence how would you evaluate this expression :

```
1+2/3
```

Well , some would say that you want to divide the sum of `1+2` by `3` . Others that you want to add `2/3` to `1` !